# "failed to download odrs.gnome.org" 18.04

Tags: updates, repository, ssl

[image]And suddenly i have this problem.
Tried the reinstall to no avail.
I'm on 18.04 and "failed to download odrs.gnome.org" SSL handshake failed.
Nothing wrong with my internet.
Seems like we changed the repository?
Since when did we change repository?
How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have not installed last system updates including updated SSL certificates.

Please run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, then reboot and launch GNOME Software again.

Comment: Yes, seems like  most things work correctly now.

Comment: and what to do for centos where apt-get command is not found??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to "Add a comment" here, so I'll answer the question that @muhammad asked in his comment:

Take a look at the "Changelog" section of [this page](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-updates-x86_64/ca-certificates-2021.2.50-72.el7_9.noarch.rpm.html).

Granted, this question of his would be better posed on the Unix & Linux SE and is OT here, but may be of interest to Ubuntu users as well.

Incidentally, the answer that @n0rbert posted is not complete:

As of the time of this answer, there is no version of the relevant package for 18.04 or even 20.04 that leaves out the offending cert. What you need to do (after doing what @n0rbert suggested, that is) is this:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`

At the first question in the resulting dialogs, answer `yes`, and on the second, arrow down to the offending cert and turn it off such that it no longer has a `*` between the `[ ]` next to it.

Comment: Hello. Comments in someone else question are not the place to ask a question.